# Why I am not able to push my code to BitBucket?

Tags: git, flutter, github, visual-studio-code, bitbucket

I am developing a `flutter` app and trying to send my code to `bitbucket`. I did the following steps.

1. go to `bitbucket` and create a new project, under that a new repository.
2. copy the repo url, something like `https://abcd@bitbucket.org/abcd/my_project.git`
3. Using terminal, navigate to my flutter app folder.
4. Type `git init`
5. Type `git remote add origin https://abcd@bitbucket.org/abcd/my_project.git`
6. Type `git add *`
7. Type `git commit -m "first commit"`
8. Type `git pull origin master`
9. Type `git add *`
10. Type `git commit -m "second commit"` (actually nothing really to commit here, i just did)
11. Type `git push origin master`

Now I get the following error

```
To https://bitbucket.org/abcd/my_project.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://bitbucket.org/abcd/my_project.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Why is this happening? I have already used `git pull origin master` in above steps as well!

Comment: Did you try simpling cloning by `https://abcd@bitbucket.org/abcd/my_project.git` and then committing and pushing files by `git commit`?

Comment: @AntonioPetricca: I cant. I am trying to push an existing project to remote repo and not the other way around.

Comment: Try with my complete answer and tell me if it works.

Comment: @AntonioPetricca: Okay, waiting for the answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue was there is a non-synced file `.gitignore`. This is not commited by default. So I had to

```
git add .gitignore
```

and

```
git commit -m "message"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should rely on a less complex process for doing the same thing.

Please try with:

```sh
git clone https://abcd@bitbucket.org/abcd/my_project.git
cd my_project
cp -rv <MY_SOURCES_PATH>/* .
git add --all
git commit -m "A comment"
git push
```

Let me know if it works.

Regards.